# WebGL GL_INVALID_OPERATION in viewer version 7

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After upgrading the viewer from version 6.5 to 7.1 we noticed this warning in the browser console log when running our existing Forge model files:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Active draw buffers with missing fragment shader outputs.
```

We have tried several of our existing models, all with the same warning displayed, without our own extensions applied, just a basic viewer. Our smallest model gives us 6 copies of the warning, while larger multi-models give us 256 copies, plus:

```
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

To us it seems like an internal issue in the viewer. Perhaps publishing new model versions would solve the issue, but it would be great if we don't have to do that.

**PS:** All our models are self-hosted (not BIM 360). We believe we have taken all the necessary actions mentioned in the [v7 migration guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/).

**EDIT:**
When running the same models in Firefox (64 bit, v68.0.1) I get a different warning message, and a reference to line 2883 in WebGLRenderer.js:

```
Error: WebGL warning: drawElements: Program has no frag output at location 1, but destination draw buffer has an attached image. 6 WebGLRenderer.js:2883

_gl.drawElements(geomType, count, type, startOffset * size); // 2 bytes per Uint16
```

Comment: Can you try clear the browser's cache or switch to another browser first? If the issue persists can you send one of the model (via a sharing service e.g. weTransfer/Dropbox/GDrive etc) to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into it?

Comment: I have followed your recommendations and added some more information for you (look at EDIT section). I also sent an example model by email. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue as well with all of our existing models. Translating the file again doesnt seem to fix the issue. Also, If the model contained only 3d poly lines, It wont be visible at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an issue in our main viewer app, with custom extensions etc. I was able to render the model correctly in a basic 7.2 viewer app. An then the "Clicking in Model Browser will now isolate objects" works as well.

So we need to do more research to find the cause. Thank you for your help, Bryan.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade to Viewer v7.2 and that should fix the issue:

> - Fixed attributesVersion bugs on pushpin’s metadata
> - Infinite recursion in Fusion Orbit
> - Reset view frustrum and clipping planes when zoomed into large model
> - MRT errors in Chrome 76

See full release notes [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-72)

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Well the warning disappeared, but so did the entire model geometry as well. The model object tree seems to be intact though.

Also the new feature "Clicking in Model Browser will now isolate objects." in v7.2 is not working. Clicking a node in the tree has no effect.

Comment: Unfortunately still unable to replicate the issue - see live demo [here](https://output.jsbin.com/ciwayuz) and screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/BzS7Yyx.png) - could it still be a cache issue?